# Google Apps Script Editor - is error elaboration possible?

Tags: google-apps-script, error-handling, ide, v8

## **TL;DR**

**How to get elaborated information about javascript errors in Google Apps Script editor itself, *BEFORE* executing the script**

### Clarification

This is NOT a question about a specific code, but about GAS editor's behavior/functionallity

### Background

When writing a line of code in GAS, the editor clearly recognizes the problems and underlines the relevant places in red zigzagged underline / 3 grey dots.

[image]

### Questions

1. Is there a way
   to see elaboration about what the problems actually are **in the editor itself**
   *BEFORE* executing the code and tracking them with `console.log` / `trycatch` / the Executions tab?

Same example, now in VSC:

[image: js expectation 1]
[image: js expectation 2]
[image: js expectation 3]
[image: issues fixed]

2. Is it possible to get even more elaboration (from ts for example), like that:

[image: async issue]
[image: onEdit1 issue]
[image: { issue]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the errors before running the script by using `Windows key + F8` / `option + F8` that will trigger the `Go to next problem`.

You can also file a Feature Request or an Issue on Google's issue tracker.

This is the template for the Feature Request:

- https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191640&template=824113